# Ускорение создания скриншота ffmpeg

Tags: linux, windows, ffmpeg, jpeg, screenshots

Делаю скриншоты c видео, 10 шт., 20 шт. или более надо сделать за раз на файл. Получается при создании нового скриншота команда проходит каждый раз сначала.

Можно ли сделать в ffmpeg так чтобы например 9 скриншотов последовательно создались без постоянного возврата к началу? Каким образом это можно объединить в один проход?

```
.\ffmpeg.exe -ss 500 -copyts -i 1.mkv -vframes 1 1.jpg
.\ffmpeg.exe -ss 1000 -copyts -i 1.mkv -vframes 1 2.jpg
.\ffmpeg.exe -ss 1500 -copyts -i 1.mkv -vframes 1 3.jpg
.\ffmpeg.exe -ss 2000 -copyts -i 1.mkv -vframes 1 4.jpg
.\ffmpeg.exe -ss 2500 -copyts -i 1.mkv -vframes 1 5.jpg
.\ffmpeg.exe -ss 3000 -copyts -i 1.mkv -vframes 1 6.jpg
.\ffmpeg.exe -ss 3500 -copyts -i 1.mkv -vframes 1 7.jpg
.\ffmpeg.exe -ss 4000 -copyts -i 1.mkv -vframes 1 8.jpg
.\ffmpeg.exe -ss 4500 -copyts -i 1.mkv -vframes 1 9.jpg
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47198241/run-ffmpeg-once-but-get-multiple-screenshots — первая ссылка в выдаче https://www.google.com/search?q=several+screenshorts+from+video+ffmpeg.

Comment: Немного уточню. Время нужного скриншота имеет разные значения, то есть 45 секунда, 118, 123, 1025 и т.п.

Comment: Такой пример не запускается, просто загружает процессор на 100% и всё.
.\ffmpeg.exe -i 1.mkv -vf "select=eq(t\,79)+eq(t\,96)+eq(t\,185)+eq(t\,260)" -vsync vfr output_%02d.png